# Lookup opetaion of Amazon Product Advertising API does not work for iOS using Pico Tutorial

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

I am working in an iOS app which need to get information using Lookup operation from [Amazon Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html).

I follow this [Pico Tutoiral](http://bulldog2011.github.io/blog/2013/03/31/pico-tutoiral-5-hello-amazon-product-advertising-api/), I can successfully show data using ItemSearch operation, But I couldn't show for Loookup operation.

I use follwoing peremeter for Lookup request, But it did not show any data.

```
// get shared client
AWSECommerceServiceClient *client = [AWSECommerceServiceClient sharedClient];
client.debug = YES;

// build request
ItemLookup *request = [[[ItemLookup alloc] init] autorelease];
request.associateTag = @"tag"; // seems any tag is ok
request.shared = [[[ItemLookupRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
request.shared.condition =@"All" ;
request.shared.idType = @"ASIN";
request.shared.itemId=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"ASIN", nil];

request.shared.merchantId=@"Amazon";

request.shared.truncateReviewsAt=0;
request.shared.variationPage=@"All";
```

For any help thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey i have donw this with ios swift 3

Answer (score 2):

The request parameter of ItemId need one or more than one ISBN no. of the book about which you need to get more information

like:

```
request.shared.itemId=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0890425558",@"1456360736", nil];
```

Here 0890425558 and 1456360736 are ISBN no of two books.

Answer (score 1):

Here itemId needs an array for search index.You can use one or more than ISBN numbers which is the unique identifier of a book to create an array.